# tabularx \hline introduces blank line above

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using `tabularx` and I successfully created some tables with it so far (not too nice ones, but thats another problem). One Table freaks me out, as the "header" is separated from the next lines not only by my usual `\hline` but also with an empty line or row it seems. Comparison with my successful tables did not give me any clue. The hopefully compilable code sniplet is:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:Nanoindent_Kenngroessen}a caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXX}
\, & Mesa0\_2 & Mesa3 & Mesa10 & Mesa15  \\ %my header
\hline
Eindringtiefe [nm] & 509,45\,\textpm\,15,52 & 344,25\,\textpm\,2,56 & 1264,56\,\textpm\,89,53 & 408,66\,\textpm\,13,42 \\
Kriechstrecke [nm] & 59,32\,\textpm\,3,71 & 37,29\,\textpm\,1,42 & 199,80\textpm 3,93 & 53,62\,\textpm\,0,46 \\
remanente Eindringtiefe [nm]& 82,08\,\textpm\,3,94 & 63,04\,\textpm\,2,38 & 294,70\,\textpm\,30,40 & 90,01\,\textpm\,13,20 \\
Relaxations\-strecke [nm] & 83,46\,\textpm\,4,23 & 64,43\,\textpm\,2,38 & 232,19\,\textpm\,9,37 & 63,33\,\textpm\,2,37
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The Result looks like this whenever I compile it. Although I use the exact same syntax for other tables, I always end up with this strange space inbetween.

[image: Table with additional line before \hline]

Comment: Remove the `\,` in the first cell.

Comment: Wow, I do not understand why that happens/results in that behavior... Anyhow, that actually helped, indeed! Kudos to you @egreg, THANKS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `\,` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 1304:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{%
   \relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\thinspace\fi
}
```

In your case, the `\,` alone in the first table cell is not scanned in math mode, so it is translated into `\thinspace`, whose definition is

```
% latex.ltx, line 1315:
\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }
```

and here the problem shows: we are *not yet* building a paragraph, because the `X` column is essentially a `\parbox`. Thus the kern is seen in vertical mode; this sets the reference point and then the implied strut at the end of the entry makes this into something like a two line paragraph.

The correct definition of `\,` should be

```
% latex.ltx, line 1304:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{%
   \relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\leavevmode\thinspace\fi
}
```

Probably nobody has ever used `\,` at the start of a paragraph (which doesn't start it, actually), so this misfeature (or maybe bug) never showed up.

However, the `\,` there serves no purpose. Remove it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this insightful, good answer, I did not even know `\,` was mathmode... Latex really has the power to make me feel like a dumb user on the one side and feeling "special" b/c I am writing source code (;

Comment: @Faultier `\,` need not be issued in math mode; the code indeed specifies different behavior for it when in math mode or not. Unfortunately, `\kern` is a strange beast that must be treated with care.